# Fetching data in React Native by using axios meet infinite loop

Tags: react-native

when I use Axios to fetch data from the server, I encountered an infinite loop.

[my code is as below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV6yr.png)

[the data I get from the server is as follows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqvP.png)

Comment: Please post the code here not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions passed to useEffect are executed on every component rendering—unless you pass a second argument to it.
If the second argument is an empty array, like the example above, it will behave exactly like the componentDidMount, only executing on the first rendering.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
const SampleComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // code to run on component mount
  }, [])//add this square bracket
return (<div>foo</div>)
}
export SampleComponent
```